# ref для каждого элемента массива useRef()

Tags: reactjs, ref

Нужно написать ref-и для каждого элемента массива

```
 {events?.map((event) => {
  return (
    <Styled.Event
      onContextMenu={handleContextMenuClick(event.id)}
      key={event.id}
      ref={ref}
      onClick={handleOpenPopover}
      data-grid={{
        x: 0,
        y: getYAxisOffset(event.start),
        w: 24,
        h: getYAxisOffset(event.end) - getYAxisOffset(event.start),
        minW: 24,
        maxW: 24,
        isDraggable: true,
        isResizable: true,
        static: true,
        isBounded: true,
      }}
    >
```

Comment: мне примерно за такой же вопрос сегодня отминусовали и ничего не ответили))) Похоже, это невозможно. Надо учить redux..

Comment: Я это сделал очень легко без ref-a